# WCF Sessions in Mono

Tags: c#, mono

Which binding should I choose to enable sessions following is my service interface:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IAkessaAbstractionService
{

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating=true)]
    LoginDTO Login(string Username, byte[] Password, bool ForcefulLogin);

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating=false)]
    string[] names();

}
```

when I use WSHttpBinding() as basicHttpBinding doesn't support sessions, I get the following error:

**Exception during finishing channel acceptance.
System.NotSupportedException: Channel type System.ServiceModel.Channels.IReplySessionChannel is not supported
at etc etc....**

and when I use WSDualHttpBinding() it throws the following error:

**System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
at System.ServiceModel.WSDualHttpBinding.CreateBindingElements () [0x00000] in :0 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding) [0x00000] in :0**

I am using mono version 2.10.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No support for WCF sessions in mono as of now.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know details of your needs...

But for doing a lot of **reliable RPC**, I use standard **.NET Remoting**.

I've designed systems with this principles:
- Server Activated Objects
- Single Call (No Singleton)
- BinaryFormatter over TCP (*in my case I've complete control over network settings*)

I use it with success in **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS**.

Regards,
Giacomo